# Creating a search function using regex - JS, mongoDB

Tags: javascript, regex, mongodb, mongoose

Here in my code I want to perform a search function. There few items in my database.

```
Eg: 1234ABO , l0987ABC , 890I45O , BVC450p etc.
```

Here what I want to do is when I search an item with similar looking characters (O vs 0 , 1 vs I vs l)
it should return the items considering those similar characters are same .
As an example lets say I accidently searched the item 890I450 as 89O1450 (0 -> O and I -> 1) it should still return the expected item. What should I do for this?

```
exports.findByName = (req, res) => {
   

    const itemName = req.params.name    
    var condition = itemName ? {
 
        itemName: { $regex: new RegExp(itemName), $options: "ix" },
        _active: true

    } : {}

    Item.find(condition)
        .then((data) => {
            res.send(data)
        })
        .catch((err) => {
            res.status(500).send({
                message: err.message || "Some error occurred while retrieving items."
            })
        })
}
```

Comment: You could start by replacing `O` and `0` with the character class `[O0]` and `1`, `I` and `l` with `[1Il]`. For `890I4O5`, the expression that you want to match becomes `89[O0][1Il]4[O0]5`.

Comment: @Scratte This is not what I wanted. In the actual database there are hundreds of items. Those are just examples. Is there any way to do it generally for all items?

Comment: I don't think I understand then. From my understanding you could have `89014O5` and `890I405` in your database. Then someone puts in a search for `89Ol405` and you want the two items returned?

Comment: @Scratte 890!405 is just an example. There are many items in my database with similar types of characters.(I,1 and l). Every time a user accidently searches for item with wrong characters, the program should return every similar items to the users input. I am doing this to make users life easier. Because we cant expect every time that user will input the correct item noh

Comment: How many items you have is irrelevant. If you are using a regex to try to find a match, searching for `abc` is only going to give you `abc` while searching for `ab[cde]` is going to give you `abc`, `abd` and `abe` (assuming they are there). So before you start to search, just turn `abc` into `ab[cde]`. Since you have identified that `O` and `0` are confused, you can just turn any search for either into a search for both with a character class.

Comment: @Scratte Okay I got your point. but in this case for items name there is no any specific pattern.As an example there are items like ABC1230 and sometimes there are items like 90PLFCR786TBCS34. This is why I can't use above regex.

Comment: That is why I explained you can do it in two steps. First fix the string you want to search for replacing the characters with a character class. Then use that in your search. Replace all `O` and `0` with `[0O]` and all `1`, `I` and `l` with `[1Il]` in `90PLFCR786TBCS34`. That makes the regex into `9[0O]PLFCR786TBCS34`. Now use that to see if anything matches. For `ABC1230` the replacing makes it `ABC[1Il]23[0O]`.

Comment: @Scratte Oh now I understand. Please could you show me how to do it in the code. Because I am new to regex. I got your whole idea. But the thing is I don't have a clear idea about how to implement it in the code. Please could you show it to me

Comment: Unfortunately I do not know enough javaScript and cannot give you a full Answer.. but this seems to work in my Console: `console.log('890I4O5'.replace(/(0|O)/g, '[0O]').replace(/(1|I|l)/g, '[1Il]'));` for the first replace step. I picked it up at MDN Web Docs for [String.prototype.replace()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace)